# the more...the more pattern with or without inversion

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

> 1- The sooner rehabilitation started and longer it lasted, the faster
> and the better ***was*** the improvement in patient's walking and
> breathing capacities. ([Article](https://medicalxpress.com/news/2020-09-covid-patients-long-term-lung-heart.html))
>
> 2- The sooner rehabilitation started and longer it lasted, the faster
> and the better the improvement in patient's walking and breathing
> capacities ***was***.

Hi, I saw the first sentence reading an article on COVID treatment and made the second sentence up. I wonder if there is any grammar rule about the placing of "was" in these sentences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't be any inversion in this kind of double comparative sentence. [Here](https://www.thoughtco.com/double-comparatives-1210274) is an article on that. (Apologies, the phrase "double comparative" is also used for a specific grammar error.) So, **only the second sentence is correct**.

I found the article you were reading on [medical xpress](https://medicalxpress.com/news/2020-09-covid-patients-long-term-lung-heart.html), and it was written by the European Lung Foundation, so it wouldn't surprise me if the first sentence was written by a non-native English speaker.

Comment: So, only sentence that works is the second one I guess?

Comment: +1 for finding bad translation. Why not spaghetticonbaguetti? :)